# Installing Task Management System without Social Office portlet

Tags: hook, portlet, liferay, shared-libraries, tms

I want to install TMS (Task Management System) from SO (Social Office) to my Liferay so that I would not install the SO first. So, it would be used as a portlet or so and I don't have to take the full amount of the other SO stuff. I have found out that I should use some hooks in there but I haven't more idea what to do.

Please, point me to some tutorial or give a short list of how to accomplish this task.

Comment: Liferay had on their SVN trunk a tms portlet source, but it was completely deleted now on the current status there. On their forums I found some package which on running the portlet gives errors on tld files. [Link](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/8043085)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They've moved the tms-portlet from the incubation repository to tasks-portlet trunk repository. You can check it out at
svn://svn.liferay.com/repos/public/plugins/trunk/

You'll find it in the portlet/tasks-portlet directory. If you need it for an older version, you might just have to check out an older revision.

Comment: How you guys contact to this repo? I am using Subclipse, but I can get only error stating: Malformed network data

Comment: Now I got it with RabbitVCS :)

Comment: Where I could find the dependencies: `portal-trunk` folder?

Comment: Have anybody tried should this code also work? Trying to manually fit in the dependencies seems to be impossible task. First of all: included .jar files should be of the trunk version, but how to generate them?

Comment: The user is "guest", and there is no password.

Comment: Thanks. Also I wanted to know where portal-trunk location can be found on the repo.

Comment: @Mikko svn://svn.liferay.com/repos/public/portal/trunk/

Comment: I don't think so. Code has a build path to `portal-trunk` with a dash between. Has anybody really get that code working, and have found this kind of project there. The reference is to `portal-trunk` PROJECT. Or did I miss sth?

Comment: @Mikko, I'm not entirely sure where this reference is but I've successfully deployed Tasks into Liferay Portal trunk using Ant.

Comment: The project dependency is to svn.liferay.com/repos/public/portal/trunk. If you import this project into eclipse, you'll see that it's named portal-trunk. From this you see that the expectation is that this portlet might not run with a released version, because this version is under development with trunk. If you're using it with a release, you might want to change the dependency to the portal source code of the release you're working with. You might also get along without any dependency to the portal itself - try it.